# How can I lower the delay after incorrectly entered login and sudo passwords?

Tags: login, sudo, password, lightdm, pam

I am horribly impatient and can't stand the (for me subjectively long) delay of around 2 seconds after entering an incorrect password in the login screen or also as `sudo` password, before I can retry typing it correctly.

Is there a way to modify the delay and reduce it to around half a second or turn it completely off, both for `sudo` and the login screen?

The optimal solution would include a longer delay after maybe 3 or 5 incorrect passwords, to still prevent brute-forcing.

PS: I am currently using vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity Desktop and lightdm.

Comment: Related (on U&L): [How does one change the delay that occurs after entering an incorrect password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40954/how-does-one-change-the-delay-that-occurs-after-entering-an-incorrect-password)

Comment: Related: [change-the-delay-that-occurs-after-entering-an-incorrect-password-in-the-graphic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245693)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Ubuntu, to **remove the delay** for incorrect passwords in the terminal, edit the file `common-auth` found in the folder `/etc/pam.d`.

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

Then add the string `nodelay` to the end of the line

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

so that it says

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure nodelay
```

Then save the file with nano by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want to instead **change the delay**, first do the step above and remove the delay completely. Then add the following line to the same file *before* the line you altered above:

```
auth       optional     pam_faildelay.so  delay=500000
```

This will be the first uncommented line of the file. If you add this line after the first line you edited, then it won't work.

Now you can edit the delay value to whatever you want. I put a half second like you wanted.

Comment: This works, but I would rather like a short (or even incremental, but I doubt this is possible without oversized effort) delay than zero. Thanks for your answer anyway, I'll accept it if nothing better comes up within the next days.

Comment: Okay, I finally figured it out. I will edit my answer to include _changing_ the delay as well.

Comment: Wonderful, that does exactly what I wanted. Thank you a lot. :)

Comment: Note also that this requires a reboot.

Comment: This works fine without reboot on Ubuntu 20.04, but only for the `sudo` command. If I log out of the graphical screen and login again, ther is still a 3s delay on a failed attempt

Answer (score 5):

If you want to *lower* the delay rather than disabling it altogether, edit `/etc/pam.d/login`:

```
sudoedit /etc/pam.d/login
```

Find the line that looks like:

```
auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=3000000
```

Change the number after `delay=` to a smaller value, as desired.
Note that the number is in microseconds, so 1000000 is 1 second.

---

Sources:

- [How does one change the delay that occurs after entering an incorrect password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40954/how-does-one-change-the-delay-that-occurs-after-entering-an-incorrect-password)
- `/etc/pam.d/login` on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system.

Comment: I edited the value to `delay=500000` (should equal 0.5s) and rebooted, but the change had no effect on the lightdm login screen. Maybe it ignores that setting and has its own configuration? It is also not used by `sudo` either.

Comment: It seems this is an outdated method. It doesn't work for me either. And, though it's not Ubuntu specifically, [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40956) are some people on stackexchange commenting about how they managed to get it to work by putting the `nodelay` into `pam_unix.so` and then afterward going to `pam_faildelay.so` and changing the delay. However, I tried doing it, and it didn't work for me either.

Comment: works fine on Ubuntu 20.04 but only for the commandline- login, not for the graphical Ubuntu-Login

Answer (score 2):

To get your system to ignore the *default password security delay* add `nodelay`  to the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file:

Change this line:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

To:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure nodelay
```

Then *reboot* the system for it to take effect.

**Note:**

Formally done here `/etc/login.defs` but now handled by *PAM* in the `/etc/pam.d` by various configuration files.