# Password checking takes long even though it's not wrong

Tags: 16.04, sudo, password

I'm aware that there is an intended delay when entering a wrong password. However, since about yesterday, my Ubuntu 16.04 takes 10-20 seconds or sometimes even more to verify the password, even though it's the right one. That problem happens on the lock screen, it happens when I use `sudo`, it doesn't matter where I type in my password.

Does anybody have an idea why that might be the case?

Comment: Are you on a network?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/877385/367990 might be related, but it's only about changing the delay after a failed password entry. Maybe it helps you to find where to look though.

Comment: @George No, everything's local.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS settings. Sometimes it cannot resolve even localhost if the line is missing from /etc/hosts.