# How to stop initial blank login attempt?

Tags: login, login-screen, lock-screen

Using ubuntu 16.04, when the screen locks and goes to sleep, whenever I press the enter key to bring up the login screen again, it always automatically makes an initial login attempt using what is currently in the password text box (which is always initially empty). Thus, end up having to wait ~5-7 seconds while it decides that the password is incorrect, before being able to actually enter any password. Is there a way to make this stop (ie. while sleeping, have the computer not *also* be waiting for password input key-presses, rather waiting until a key is pressed before waking up and *then* expecting password input)? This is not a behavior that I have experience with windows, mac, or other linux OSs (eg. cent OS) and am hoping that I can keep that here with ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: Is the key you're pressing the `Enter` key?

Comment: Does this even happen if you wake up the computer by moving the mouse or pressing a key like Ctrl or Alt that doesn't input anything? Also, if you want to lower the delay after entering an incorrect password, [check out my question here](https://askubuntu.com/q/877385/367990).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Yes. Does that make the question a bit silly to ubuntu users (I legitimately don't know)? This is not a behavior that I have experienced in mac, windows, or other version of linux (eg. cent OS). I'd prefer if I could set it to not be listening for password key presses while the screen is locked, *until* I hit a key (including "enter"), at which point it would wake up and start listening for input key-presses. In any case, I will update the question.

Comment: Generally I just start typing in my password at the lock screen, due to which I find the Mac/Windows behaviour annoying, since the first keypress is lost.

Comment: Heh, interesting: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314569/are-there-ways-to-have-mac-os-recognize-my-password-better Somebody asks for the opposite on Macs.