# Change the delay that occurs after entering an incorrect password in the gdm3 login-screen?

Tags: login, gdm, pam

I am very impatient, when I unfortunately mistype my login-password on my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04), I don't want to wait three seconds to retry. (A delay of 0.3 seconds would be enough to prevent potential brute force and there is a longer time after 3 failed attempts anyway.)

I found a lot of answers explaining how to change this delay for the **console login** and for `sudo`. I managed to set that delay to 0.3 seconds by editing the value in `/etc/pam.d/login` (for the **tty console**) to:

```
auth       optional     pam_faildelay.so  delay=300000
```

and adding the same line to `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` (for **sudo** and the **graphical login screen**) as first line before (!) this line:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure nodelay
```

See:

- [Change login timeout when logging in into Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396532/change-login-timeout-when-logging-in-into-ubuntu/62127700#62127700) on stackoverflow
- [How can I lower the delay after incorrectly entered login and sudo passwords](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877385/how-can-i-lower-the-delay-after-incorrectly-entered-login-and-sudo-passwords) on askubuntu

This kind of changes the delay that occurs on the **graphical gdm3 login-screen in Ubuntu 20.04** but only until the login input field reappears (and **shakes**). If you set a long delay in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`, it counts only for the time before the input field reappears. It has no effect on the delay **after the shaking**.

I already activated logging in gdm and [this is the output of `grep gdm3 /var/log/syslog`](https://paste.toppoint.de/?b3659edbee3ad72e#+Nx+lxQ+8Ys/OWPbjfQAVDQpPVI3rdup1Cs5b+AwHyU=) when I pressed <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to Lock screen and tried about 6 times a false password; you see the 3s delay in the attempt. At the end of each false password attempt, there is a log:

```
reauthentication service 'gdm-password' stopped
```

after this there starts the 3s delay until I get a new cursor. Maybe this is the main problem?

---

Update:
For info: I use GNOME Shell 3.36.1. An Idea of mine was maybe disable the shaking animation will help? Because I found out, that you can **use the mouse to click into the field** and you can type immmediately while the box is shaking.

Comment: You really shouldn't lower the delay. It's there to make brute-force attacks on your system less effective. Take your time, try to type the username and/or password correct the first time, or relax the little time it takes. Security has its costs.

Comment: @rubo77 yes, but you need both changes at the same time. Remove the default delay and add a custom one, if you want to express it like this, instead of changing it.

Comment: I guess it has to do something with the focus being set to the input field for the password in an unfortunate manner. Is the login screen programmed in html with CSS?

Comment: if you are concenred about brute forcing then just set retries to 20 , you are unlikely to typo that many times

Comment: I think what @ByteCommander meant was to disable the original using `nodelay` and type in your own custom line instead. Also, when you are addressing a fairly busy user, especially a mod, @ to ping them or your reply will most likely go unnoticed. You probably know this as you are an experienced user. I assume you forgot that time?

Comment: Read this a bit. I didn't read it through as my wifi is super slow at the moment. I will read through and update tomorrow. Meanwhile someone else can do it and say whether it can help? https://books.google.lk/books?id=w0MnCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=how+to+change+the+delay+in+login+screen+in+ubuntu&source=bl&ots=Ls8KkxydPL&sig=ACfU3U0kIwZ47OuQhnH8wbKau3UpSaazyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj14O3AnI7qAhXKIbcAHUJ0CfAQ6AEwC3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20change%20the%20delay%20in%20login%20screen%20in%20ubuntu&f=false

Comment: @ashvatthama I cannot type while the box is shaking and not the next 3 seconds. so there is something different on my system than yours, maybe because I also have installed `kubuntu-desktop` but still use Ubuntu?

Comment: You can see our chat, where we figured out the problem here in our [discussion-between-rubo77-and-ashvatthama](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109587/discussion-between-rubo77-and-ashvatthama)

Comment: @SorenA if you're worried about brute-forcing your password, make it complex enough to not be brute-forceable. A delay, especially for a local login, will only annoy the rightful user. Hackers trying to brute-force through ssh can still open new connections and won't be affected by that delay or any retry delay. Security by denial of service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging into the gnome-shell and gdm source code, the problem seems to have been fixed by these two commits:

- [f4d90bc127ececb653ee399493839f17932b7622](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/commit/f4d90bc127ececb653ee399493839f17932b7622) - "polkitAgent: Reset the session request timeout when removing it"
- [8d139bbd95a5d62e0ba20b711a10a8b669cb9e9d](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/commit/8d139bbd95a5d62e0ba20b711a10a8b669cb9e9d) - "authPrompt: Grab key focus when making entry sensitive"

These fix the issue where the input box doesn't get focused for 3 seconds after the shaking stops.

These changes are there in Gnome 3.36.2, and updating to that version fixes the issue. Now you can type even while the box is shaking.

To disable the shaking see @PRATAP's answer.

Comment: seems this is the perfect fit.. can you also include the steps how to update to the version 3.36.3

Comment: @PRATAP Ubuntu 20.04 has an update for Gnome 3.63.2, which fixes the issue according to OP rubo77 (looks like just 3.63.2 is enough), so just `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: I'm finding that the problem still exists with 3.36.3 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
_(@ashvatthama I think you have a typo in the version number in your previous comment.)_

Comment: @CourtneyMiles hmmm... could you post the outputs of  `gresource extract /usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so /org/gnome/shell/ui/components/polkitAgent.js` and `gresource extract /usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so /org/gnome/shell/gdm/authPrompt.js` please?

Comment: @ashvatthama `polkitAgent.js` - https://pastebin.com/EkY2nrgy / `authPrompt.js` - https://pastebin.com/AcqB3Qhs -- Thanks for taking a deeper look at this.

Comment: @CourtneyMiles thanks. these files don't appear to have the fixes added in 3.36.3...

Comment: After reviewing the Git commit from this answer, based on the Git tags these corrections look like they will appear in 3.37.1 rather than 3.36.2.  FYI @ashvatthama

Comment: @CourtneyMiles strange, I have these fixes in my install of Gnome 3.36.3 and so does OP apparently. has Ubuntu patched it in earlier than Gnome's official release?

Answer (score 1):

***Workaround*** based on the update in the Question

> An Idea of mine was maybe disable the shaking animation will help?
> Because I found out, that you can use the mouse to click into the
> field and you can type immediately while the box is shaking.

Shacking animation can be disabled if you wish to stop the global animation by running the below command for the desktop session..

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

The above command helps for the lock screen..

[image]

If you wish to disable the shacking animation for the login screen too..
run the below command..

```
sudo -Hu gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

for reverting above changes..

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations true
```

and

```
sudo -Hu gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations true
```

Tested in Ubuntu 20.04 for both lock and login screens..

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could disable animations that way. Also how did you manage to screen record the login screen?

Comment: @ashvatthama no, thats not the login screen.. It is lock screen.. that means you are still in your session.. so what ever the tool you use to record.. it works..

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. I'll try to include a screen recording in my answer as well now.